# E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

Tags: delphi-xe5

При компиляции кода из Delphi 2010 в XE5 возникает ошибка.

```
 if( not GetExitCodeProcess( ProcessInfo.hProcess, pExitCode^ ) )then begin
                 pExitCode^ := 0;
               end;
```

В модуле Winapi.Windows объявлена

```
function GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess: THandle; var pExitCode: PDWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Comment: А сообщение ошибки есть? А лучше стектрейс.

Comment: А какой тип у переменных? Посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

Функция `GetExitCodeProcess` вызывается из функции ниже

```
function WaitProcess( FileName:AnsiString; CommandLine:AnsiString = ''; CurrentDir:AnsiString = ''; pExitCode:PDWORD = nil ):BOOLEAN;
var
    StartupInfo : _STARTUPINFOA;
    ProcessInfo : TProcessInformation;
    WaitRes     : DWORD;
    Msg         : TMsg;
    Done        : BOOLEAN;
begin
...
end;
```

Её объявление вроде верно

```
function WaitProcess( FileName:AnsiString; CommandLine:AnsiString = ''; CurrentDir:AnsiString = ''; pExitCode:PDWORD = nil ):BOOLEAN;
```